# TinyMCE template file location

Tags: tinymce

I use TinyMCE on my site. 
I have PHP file in root on my website, in which I have user interface with editor and TinyMCE setting also with template settings:

```
templates : [
    {
            title : "Editor Details",
            src : "template/theme.htm",
            description : "Adds Editors Name and Staff ID"
    }
```

]

root/tinymce contain all tinymce files.
root/template contain theme.html

Theme.html

```
<div class="mceTmpl">
<p>Some code</p>
</div>
```

My question is - where i should put theme.html - because I see title, description, but i still getting undefined in body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I find solution. It work's with url instead of src. So in TinyMCE init should be:

```
templates : [
    {
            title : "Editor Details",
            url : "template/theme.htm",
            description : "Adds Editors Name and Staff ID"
    }
```